# Status 200 with sc-win32-status of 64 large request

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

windows server 2016
.net core 3.1 first request more than 25S.but my machine only 4S.
client only request 1/s.but iis log record more than 200/s.
log record is:
sc-win32-status of 64,timetoken 0
sc-win32-status of 64,timetoken 10ms
....
like this.

Answer (score 1):

SC-status(http status code) and sc-win-32 status=64 may happen in the following scenario.

****Scenario 1**:**
IIS get request from client and execute the request without problem. Then send back response, sc-status is 200, but we don’t know if the client has received the response and sc-win32-status.

Then IIS try to send the response to the client, but the connection is already lost (during the execution of the requestor) or gets lost during the transmission (this is a network issue). IIS log will record sc-win32-status=64, means the specified network is no longer available.

**Scenario 2:**
IIS get request from client and execute the request without problem. Then send back response, sc-status is 200, but we don’t know if the client has received the response and sc-win32-status.

Then IIS send response to the server and waits for a ACK message from the client, but client is unwilling of sending this(client gets a response). Instead, client resets the connection, to free up resources(instead of leaving the connection in a TIME_WAIT/CLOSE_WAIT state, which is more common). Since IIS did not get any ACK message, it logs a sc-win32-status code of 64.

---

As a result.

1. If you see sc-status = 200, sc-win32-status = 64 and a large time-taken value in the first access after site published, it is normally to take long time.
2. You can try to change other network, sometimes network causes many problems but we can do nothing.
3. You can check your code and connection to database, maybe some resources, connections and logical processing take long time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe server2016,
I have observed that only https can cause this problem. http is normal.

Comment: Can you be sure that the ssl certificate used is OK? The certificate verification time may be too long and the connection may be lost.